# JBoss AS 4.0.x attacked

Tags: jboss

I have an application running on JBoss Applicatoin server  (version 4.0.2) and its binded to a public address. Recently I found out some weird files and folders in one of my application folder. The weird files include 
bm.c , bm.h , bm.o , fly.pl , lindb.pl, pns, pnscan.c, pnscan.o , pns, ipsort, install-sh. These files generate some processes running on my server. When I do a ps - ef | grep pnscan, the result is :

```
 ps -ef | grep pnscan
```

`root      4159 20125  0 15:43 ?   00:00:00 sh -c ./pnscan -r JBoss -w "HEAD / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" -t 6400 229.110.0.0/16 8080 > /tmp/sess_0088025413980486928597bff110229`

`root      4160  4159  5 15:43 ?   00:00:00 ./pnscan -r JBoss -w HEAD / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n -t 6400 229.110.0.0/16 8080`

`root      4173  2751  0 15:43 pts/1    00:00:00 grep pnscan`

I couldn't kill these process as after I killed, they appeared again.

I search abt the problem and get this resolution https://access.redhat.com/kb/docs/DOC-30741 . I follow the instruction to remove the http get/set in the security constraint in the xml file deploy/jmx-console.war/WEB-INF/web.xml . After that I removed all weirds files , restart the server. Things run fine but after a while I found the weird files & folder again.

Any advice ?

Comment: http://community.jboss.org/blogs/mjc/2011/10/20/statement-regarding-security-threat-to-jboss-application-server

Comment: possible duplicate of [My server's been hacked EMERGENCY](http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency)